# whereJsonContains Laravel 5.6 not working?

Tags: php, mysql, json, eloquent, laravel-5.6

```
$rosters = EventRosters::where('event_id', $event_id)
    ->whereJsonContains('players', $user_id)
    ->whereNull('deleted_at')
    ->get();
```

The eloquent query above seems to only work when there is a single item in the 'players' json array.

The data stored in the database looks as follows:
`[1]` vs `["1","2"]`

Is there a reason the whereJsonContains is only working when it sees `[1]` in the db but not when it sees `["1","2"]` ?

I am pretty new to Laravel and have been struggling with this one a bit.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The data types have to match:

```
// [1, 2]
->whereJsonContains('players', 1)   // Works.
->whereJsonContains('players', '1') // Doesn't work.

// ["1", "2"]
->whereJsonContains('players', '1') // Works.
->whereJsonContains('players', 1)   // Doesn't work.
```

Comment: why does it save a single in the db as [1] but when there are multiple it saves as ["1","2"], instead of saving the single as ["1"] as well?

Comment: How are you saving them?

Comment: $roster->players = json_encode($players,true); where $players is an array

Comment: What are the contents of `$players`?

Comment: when it is a single user it is like this: (output of print_r($players,true) ) 
`Array ( [0] => 1 )` with multiple users it is: `Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 3 )`. The first would save to db as [1] and the second as ["1","3"]

Comment: Please check `$roster->players` after you set it. Does it contain integers or integer strings?

Comment: `$roster->players = json_encode($request->players,true); 
die($roster->players);` is giving me ["1"] or ["1","3"]

Comment: Values from HTML forms are always strings. You can convert them to integers with something like this: `$players = array_map('intval', $request->players);`

Comment: This seems to be the fix I needed. Thanks a ton for working through it with me :)

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is kinda straight forward

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#json-where-clauses

```
$rosters = EventRosters::where('event_id', $event_id)
    ->whereJsonContains(['players', [1,2]])
    //->whereNull('deleted_at') Unless you setup a scope at the model's bootup, 
    //Eloquent won't fetch soft deleted records
    ->get();
```

Depending on what you've got in that json column (if id), replace `players` with `players->id`

Comment: 'players' contains [1] or ["1","2"].
$user_id is the id of the user (ie: 1)
I am just looking for a single id that is found within ["1","2"] but it doesn't seem to find it.

Comment: then you're probably saving them wrong most likely. Probably you're submitting something and it's reading and storing as a string

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem with orWhere

```
$id = "1" // or = 1
Model::whereJsonContains('ids', [$id])
  ->orWhere(function (Builder $q) use ($model) {
    $q->whereJsonContains('ids', [(string)$id]);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FoodItemsName::leftJoin('food_items','food_items.fk_food_id','food_item_name.id')
                    ->where('food_item_name.name', 'like', '%' . $food_item . '%')
                    ->where('food_items.meal_time_id',$meal_time_id)
                    ->whereJsonContains('food_item_name.fk_diet_group_id',[(int)$user->fk_diet_group_id])
                    ->select('food_items.id', 'food_item_name.name', 'food_items.calorie_count as kcal', 'food_item_name.icon as image')
                    ->distinct('food_item_name.name')
                    ->paginate(50);
```