# Laravel whereJsonContains query not working in 5.7

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel

I have been facing a problem in my project. I want to search my json data. But could not achieve to do this. Here is my query

```
$variations = User::whereJsonContains('addon->ram', '>', 0)->count();
return $variations;
```

And My json data is stored in the `addon` column and the data is

```
{"ram":"87","base-driven":"89"}
```

In this query I am getting error says

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from
>   `users` where 0 json_contains(`addon`->'$."ram"', ">")

I google it but could not solve this

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [whereJsonContains Laravel 5.6 not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51545655/wherejsoncontains-laravel-5-6-not-working)

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu No Sir, I did not get any solution

Answer (score 1):

Just try this

```
$variations = User::where('addon->ram', '>', 0)->count();
return $variations;
```

and let time know, if you get some error.

As you are saving it as string, you may need to do something like

`WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(addon, "$[ram]") > 0;` in Laravel

Comment: @HabibHassan what error you are getting and Can you post, the sample data from your table, also Can you make the change the `0`  to  `'0'` and test?

Comment: I have been added my sample data and the error in my question. Please take a look

Comment: @HabibHassan are you getting same error for my code too?

Comment: Okay, I think it is because you have store this as string, the mathematical operators are not working for you. I think you need to find out a way to cast and compare.

Comment: @HabibHassan Also you can check [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#json-where-clauses), you do not need whereJsonConatins here, simple where will be okay.

Comment: @HabibHassan Also edited my answer, that may give you some idea.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189878/discussion-between-prafulla-kumar-sahu-and-habib-hassan).

Comment: @HabibHassan Can you try a raw query in your phpmyadmin? `SELECT * FROM users WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(addon, "$[ram]") > 0;` and let me know the output.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of you are providing "87" and "89" as strings. Try to replace it with numbers:

```
{"ram":87,"base-driven":89}
```

Comment: @HabibHassan Are you able to replace `"87"` to `87`?

Comment: Yes I replace it