# Using Json properties in where clause laravel

Tags: php, mysql, json, database, laravel

I have this table `discounts` were I have a column called `rules` which is a `json` and it has `book` array inside it like this

Table Discounts:

```
Column Rules:

rules:"{\"books\":[1,2],others..}
```

Now I want to check through Books table wheather that particular book consist in any `discounts->rules->books` or not !

What I have Tried is this:

```
$discount = Discount:: whereJsonContains('rules->books',$this->id)->get();
```

But this is returning me empty array .

Comment: hope you will find your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51545655/wherejsoncontains-laravel-5-6-not-working

Answer (score 0):

The data types have to match:

```
// [1, 2]
Discount::whereJsonContains('rules->books', 1)   // Works.
Discount::whereJsonContains('rules->books', '1') // Doesn't work.

// ["1", "2"]
Discount::whereJsonContains('rules->books', '1') // Works.
Discount::whereJsonContains('rules->books', 1)   // Doesn't work.
```

Comment: I think data type is matching Can u see my code I have used $this->id 
I think this will do like 1 not "1" right ?

Comment: Only one way to to check that! die and dump with `dd(gettype($variable))`