# Laravel query json column array

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to access specific data in a json column using a laravel controller, the DB column is called 'figuresinorder'. I want to access the "wants" key but it's not working when there are multiple values stored.

{"wants": ["1"], "trades": ["12,33,234"]} - this works

{"wants": ["1,2,3"], "trades": ["12,33,234"]} - does not work

The query in the controller is as follows:

```
$figures2 = customtrades::whereJsonContains('figuresinorder->wants', ['1'])->get();
```

Any help will be greatly received, been stuck on this for longer than I dare to admit.

Comment: Will be `{"wants": ["1","2","3"], "trades": ["12,33,234"]}`

Comment: insomniac22. Are you sure that searhching for ["1"] would return TRUE if the source is ["1,2,3"]. I would guess it would work if you search for ["1,2,3"].

Comment: ["1,2,3"] is array has one string, your problem is storing data. should be: ["1", "2", "3"]

Comment: Sta - the data is stored directly by laravel in that format, I have tried using the format you suggested but this does still not return the required data. 

Toolbox - When the query works is does return the collection correctly rather than a TRUE statement. I need to be able to search directly for the individual number id's rather than the whole array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**MySQL** & **PostgreSQL** support `whereJsonContains()` with multiple values like this way :

```
customtrades::whereJsonContains('figuresinorder->wants', ['1','2','3'])->get();
```

For more, see the  documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#json-where-clauses)

Comment: The OP wants to return any row where `wants` contains a `1` this doesnt do that

Comment: The way I'm storing the data is incorrect as stated in the first comment. When updating the DB column values I get the required response. Surprising as the stored data is the way laravel is storing data from my session. Thanks for your help Sta.

Comment: @Wesley according to the official documentation, you need to sort the dara like the above method

Comment: @insomniac22 Selecting this as the correct answer is misleading and incorrect. As you stated, the issue was in the way you were _storing_ the data, _not_ in the way you were selecting it

Comment: @sta Please add a comment along the lines of  "You are storing your data incorrectly as  a comma separated string instead of an array. If you change your storing to properly store an array of strings, then your original attempt will work as expected" This would be a correct answer if it included that or something similar.

Comment: @Wesley I added the documentation link, would you please  see that. Also this answer on SO https://stackoverflow.com/a/51545767/4575350

Comment: I see those, but they dont have anything to do with the issue, the issue was that the op was storing `["1,2,3"]` instead of `["1", "2", "3"]`. After changing the stored data, the original `whereJsonContains('figuresinorder->wants', ['1'])` would work just fine. Your answer simply looks for multiple values which has nothing to do with the actual issue and will be misleading for future readers.