# How to retrieve data based on json column matching with special data

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel

`delivery_charges` table has a json type column named `locations`. this column has the following data

```json
[{"district_id":"1"},{"district_id":"2"},{"district_id":"3"}]
```

But `$deliveryCharges` is always an empty array when I run this code:

```php
$deliveryCharges = DB::table('delivery_charges')
    ->whereJsonContains('locations->district_id',post('district_id'))
    ->get();

dump(post('district_id')); // outputs 1
dump($deliveryCharges);    // outputs []
```

I can see value of `post('district_id')` is 1. And when I comment `whereJsonContains()` lines it return the data. So it seems to me there is a problem in my where clause.

Comment: Perhaps this will provide insight: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51545655/wherejsoncontains-laravel-5-6-not-working#51545767

Comment: You aren't selecting anything. Add a `select('*')` method in there for clarity. What does `post()` do? I'm voting to close based on the discrepancy between given column name `location` and code `locations`. Please advise if this is an error in the question.

Comment: check your mysql version >5.7 or not

Answer (score -1):

If your column is named **location**, in the where clause you are named **locations**. Just use the correct column name:

```
$query->whereJsonContains('location->district_id',post('district_id'));
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```php
$deliveryCharges = DB::table('delivery_charges')
    ->where('locations','LIKE','%"district_id":"'.post('district_id') .'"%')
    ->get();
```